# Importing Locally Trained TensorFlow Model to Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm training my own model on Google Magenta (MusicVAE), and I'm using my own music files and trained the model locally on my computer. I'm having trouble figuring out how to load this model into Google Colab in order to use the model. Does anyone know how to load a locally trained model onto Google Colab?

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've uploaded my files to Google Drive and then mounted my Drive to Colab in order to access the files. I went looking for documentation for that, and found this page that also explains how to upload files directly:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb

Will one of these solutions work for you?

Some extra notes:

- If the model is big, uploading to Drive might not be an option
- Make sure you use the same Python/TensorFlow versions in Colab < lots of headaches in the past